# Document's default location has been changed

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, dropbox

My Ubuntu Home folder **Documents**' location has been changed. I mean on in Nautilus on the left panel where the **Places** are showing , if there I click on Documents it opens this location "*~/Dropbox/Documents/*". I wanna change it to default location i.e "*~/Documents/*".
How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here enter this into terminal

```
nano ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

and edit the line

```
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="WhatSoEverThePathIs"
```

to

```
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
```

then, finally press **Ctrl+O** (english letter 0 not zero) and hit enter to save.

Comment: Thanks for sharing with me the process to edit this by command line method. But I've already solved by above method.

Answer (score 3):

One of the easiest, graphical ways is using ubuntu-tweak tool. Install ubuntu-tweak using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

and then open ubuntu-tweak by typing "ubuntu tweak" on the dash. Then go to **Admins -> User Folder**. Here click on "Document" and then on "Change" and then choose the directory you want as your "Documents" folder.